# Creating a shell script with diff function to compare multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have five different files and all are in different directory, I want to check matching files and find out the unique files as well.

I am not sure how should I handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look to the output of

```
chksum "path1/file1" "path2/f2" "p3/f3" "p4/f4" "p5/f5" | sort
```

You can also make a script looping through the files with

```
files=("path1/file1" "path2/f2" "p3/f3" "p4/f4" "p5/f5")
for i in {0..4}; do
    ((j=$i+1))
    while [ $j -le 4 ]; do
       diff "${files[i]}" "${files[j]}" >/dev/null
       if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
           echo "${files[i]} and ${files[j]} are the same."
       else
           echo "${files[i]} and ${files[j]} are different."
       fi
       ((j++))
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cksum ou md5sum to detect identical files :

```
 find . -type f | while read f; do md5sum "$f"; done > tmp.txt

 cat  tmp.txt | cut -d" " -f1 | while read c
 do  n=`grep $c tmp.txt | wc -l`
 if [ "$n" != "1" ]; then 
    grep $c tmp.txt
 fi
 done | sort -u
```